# breakout dates in html table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, haml

Is there an easier way to do this?

controller:

```
def index
  @ranches = Ranch.all
  dates = (Date.today..Date.today + 52.weeks).select(&:sunday?)
  @date_range = dates
  dates.each do |date|
    month = date.strftime("%b")
    year = date.strftime("%Y")
    @dates ||= {}
    @dates[year] ||= {}
    @dates[year][month] ||= []
    @dates[year][month] << date
  end
```

view:

```
%table{:border => 1}
  %thead
    %tr
      %th{:rowspan => 3}
        Ranch
      - @dates.each do |year,months|
        -# raise months.inspect
        %th{:colspan => months.collect{|m| m[1]}.flatten.count }
          = year
    %tr
      - @dates.each do |year,months|
        - months.each do |month, days|
          %th{:colspan => days.count}
            = month
    %tr
      - @dates.each do |year,months|
        - months.each do |month, days|
          - days.each do |day|
            %th
              = day.day
```

This is the output I am getting / looking for:

[image: html table with year month day breakout]

Adding to this, I am also going to be something like the following (this will be the next and following rows:

```
%tbody
  - @ranches.each do |ranch|
    %tr
      %td
        = ranch.name
      - ranch.placements.each do |placement|
        - @date_range.each do |date|
          - start_date = date
          - end_date = date.end_of_week
          - if (start_date..end_date).include?(placement.placement_date)
            %td
              = placement.value
```

I have not figured out the colspan, etc for this part yet.  I am hoping there is some magical rails way to do this stuff so it looks better and works better.  I am open to most any suggestion.

Comment: why would you delete my thanks?  I am not opposed to it, but is there a rule I missed about that?

Comment: No rule, but it's common to edit down a question to just the meat. I'm sure no offense was intended, and nobody will think you rude for not having thanks in advance.

Comment: +1 for a fun problem (and properly semantic HTML ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Behold the power of [`Enumerable#group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) and [`Enumerable#chunk`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk)!

```ruby
require 'date'
require 'haml'

now = Date.today
next_sunday = now - now.wday + 7
@sundays = (0...52).map { |w| next_sunday + 7*w }

puts Haml::Engine.new(<<ENDHAML).render(binding)
%table
  %thead
    %tr
      - @sundays.group_by(&:year).each do |year,days|
        %th{colspan:days.length}= year
    %tr
      - @sundays.chunk{ |d| d.strftime('%b') }.each do |month,days|
        %th{colspan:days.length}= month
    %tr
      - @sundays.each do |date|
        %th= date.day
ENDHAML
```

Produces:

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan='46'>2012</th>
      <th colspan='6'>2013</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan='2'>Feb</th>
      <th colspan='4'>Mar</th>
      <th colspan='5'>Apr</th>
      <th colspan='4'>May</th>
      <th colspan='4'>Jun</th>
      <th colspan='5'>Jul</th>
      <th colspan='4'>Aug</th>
      <th colspan='5'>Sep</th>
      <th colspan='4'>Oct</th>
      <th colspan='4'>Nov</th>
      <th colspan='5'>Dec</th>
      <th colspan='4'>Jan</th>
      <th colspan='2'>Feb</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>19</th>
      <th>26</th>
      <th>4</th>
      <th>11</th>
      <th>18</th>
      <th>25</th>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>8</th>
      <th>15</th>
      <th>22</th>
      <th>29</th>
      <th>6</th>
      <th>13</th>
      <th>20</th>
      <th>27</th>
      <th>3</th>
      <th>10</th>
      <th>17</th>
      <th>24</th>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>8</th>
      <th>15</th>
      <th>22</th>
      <th>29</th>
      <th>5</th>
      <th>12</th>
      <th>19</th>
      <th>26</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>9</th>
      <th>16</th>
      <th>23</th>
      <th>30</th>
      <th>7</th>
      <th>14</th>
      <th>21</th>
      <th>28</th>
      <th>4</th>
      <th>11</th>
      <th>18</th>
      <th>25</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>9</th>
      <th>16</th>
      <th>23</th>
      <th>30</th>
      <th>6</th>
      <th>13</th>
      <th>20</th>
      <th>27</th>
      <th>3</th>
      <th>10</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: That is beautiful, and Thank you!  I love Ruby (and Rails, but I see your answer is Ruby, amazing)!  Now I think that even points me in the right direction for the other part of this question.  If I can't figure that out I will just make it a new question though.

Comment: @Toby Glad to have helped! Do ask new, more targeted questions for any further problems you're having. :)